# Поиск в строке С++

Tags: строки, c++

Я написал две процедуры:

```
- запись в файл
- считывание из файла
```

Теперь мне скорее всего надо считывать не в консоль, а в массив и сверять элементы этого массива с данными введенными в консоль, например "Воронин".
Но как организовать считывание строки из файла так, чтобы он заносил в массив элементы пропуская разделитель этих элементов.
Например, "Воронин+Петр:Иванович".
Можно же сделать считывание фамилии до знака "+", а считывание имени от знака "+" до ":"?

Answer (score 2):

Масса вариантов. Меньше всего писать при использовании регулярных выражений.

Comment: Регулярные выражения? Я про них до сих пор ничего не слышал. Можете дать источник, где имеется их описание. Буду благодарен.

Answer (score 2):

Разделите свою задачу на подзадачи: (1) прочитайте всю строку в память, (2) разбейте её на части, (3) положите нужные части в массив. Для задачи №2 можно воспользоваться как регулярными выражениями (это — хорошая техника, обязательно выучите их), так и разобрать строку вручную (найти индекс знаков `+` и `:`, выделить соответствующие подстроки).

Comment: Это восхитительный метод, спасибо!